# word breaking using recursive method

Tags: python-3.x

What confuses me is why the code produces different results, one with output, the other no output, why?

These two lines

```
st=st[i: ]
word_break_recur(dic, st, res )
```

produced results:

```
['word', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', 'problem']
['word', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', 'problem', 'ak', 'problem']
['word', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', 'problem', 'ak', 'problem', 'break', 'problem']
```

if combined the two lines into one,

```
word_break_recur(dic, st[i: ], res )
```

produced nothing!

*Below is the full code.*

```
def word_break_recur(dic, st, res):
    leng=len(st)
    if leng==0:
        print(res)
        return 
    for i in range(leng):
        pre_st=st[: i]
        if pre_st in dic:
            res.append(pre_st)
            st=st[i: ]  #if combine these lines, as word_break_recur(dic, st[i: ], res )
            word_break_recur(dic, st, res )  #it gives totally different results

dic=['this', 'th', 'is', 'famous', 'word', 'break', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', 'br', 'bre', 'brea', 'ak', 'problem']
string='wordbreakproblem'
res=[]
res=word_break_recur(dic, string, res)
```

Comment: **@Luke_ic**, please add few more details about the **output** that you expect from the recursive function. Format the code as well, it is not clear (function is not properly indented). It will help us to help you in much better way.